# Remove url param with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, url, replace

Given a url, I'm trying to remove a particular url parameter.

For example, if I had:

```
http://example.com?foo=bar&baz=boo
```

And I wanted to get rid of `foo=bar` and be left with:

```
http://example.com?baz=boo
```

Or if I wanted to remove `baz=boo` I would be left with:

```
http://example.com?foo=bar
```

I'm trying to use a regular expression along with the string's `replace` function.

Here's what I have:

```
// s is "foo"
new RegExp("([&?]+)" + s + "=.*&")
```

It's not working for the case of:

```
http://example.com?foo=bar
```

Because it's not matching the `&`, but I can't figure out how to craft the regex to handle both of these situations.

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/humicuhido/edit?js,console)

Comment: In case of just `foo=bar` do you want `?` to be left ? In case you want to append something after it.

Comment: @noob I suppose I'd prefer it to be gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/85/)**

I think that what you looking for, using group to deal with the both cases with `&` and without it :

```
"([&?]+)" + s + "=(.*&|.*$)?"
```

**Edit :**
**[Update fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/87/)**

You could add `?` if you want to stop on the first occurance of `&` (if exist) :

```
"([&?]+)" + s + "=(.*?&|.*$)?"
_____________________^
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very close, but if there are three params like `http://example.com?foo=bar&baz=boo&fliz=flap` and you remove `foo=bar` the `&` is greedy and removes `baz=boo`.  Does that mean that a positive look-ahead is required?

Answer (score 1):

`([&?]+)foo=.*?(?:&|$)` should work.

## What I changed

- `.*?` fixes greediness issues.
- `(?:&|$)` is a non-capturing group. It either matches a `&` or it matches the line end (with `$`).

Comment: Did you considered case of `baz=boo`, Because it doesn't seems to be working for it.

Comment: The non-capturing group seems to be capturing till the end of the line (https://regex101.com/r/eZ5lT1/1). Do you know how to make it non-greedy?

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink Fixed (the problem was in the part that you wrote, FYI.)

Comment: @noob I modified `/*s=foo;*/   new RegExp("([&?]+)" + s + "=.*&")` into a single regex for simplicity. He should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = str.replace(/(?:\?|&)(foo[^=]*=[^&]+)(?:&|$)/,'');
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/rB9jA2/1)